# Homomorphic Encryption - Integer modulus in HEAAN and key sampling

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, key-size, key-generation

I am trying to wrap my head around Homomorphic encryption, specifically the HEAAN/CKKS scheme. I am reading through the [publication](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/421.pdf), but I am getting stuck on page 11, namely the KeyGen and Enc functions.

My issue in understanding comes from the generation of the public key:
$$
p.k.\leftarrow (b,a)
$$
$$
b \leftarrow-as+e(modq_L)
$$
$$
q_l = p^l\cdot q_0
$$
where $l$ denotes the multiplicative level, $0<l\leq L$, and $a$ is sampled uniformly from $R_{qL}$. For my question's sake, lets assume that a polynomial coefficient for vector $a$ happens to be $q_L-1$. When encoding a message $m$, which is defined as
$$
v \cdot p.k. + (m + e0, e1)(mod q_L)
$$

and  $e0$/$e1$ being Gaussian errors, isn't it likely that there would be an overflow of the coefficients, causing inaccuracies in the decoded output? Should $a$ be sampled over $q_1$ (the integer modulus of level 1) as opposed to the maximum integer modulus $q_L$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the multiplicative depth $L$ and thus the selection of your ciphertext modulus $Q_L$ is important for guaranteeing a certain number ($L$) of correct ciphertext multiplications before needing to bootstrap the ciphertext. After once selecting $L$ resp. $Q_L$, it is fixed for the scheme, i.e. all future operations/encryptions. Apart from that, $L$ is an independent parameter, which has no "impact" on the correctness of the techniques of Encoding, Encrypting, Decrypting, etc.

Now turning to what I believe is what you wanted to know: Indeed there is an overflow of $a$, i.e. the uniformly sampled "random component" of the ciphertext. Especially when you multiply $a$ with the secret key and add an error and a message $m$, you should not be able to retrieve $m$, due to the fact that they are overflowing the modulus (by far) and thus look completely random afterward (RLWE security is based on that construction). But there is a technique to protect $m$ from small errors: Encoding $m$ via a scaling factor ($\Delta$ in the paper) ensures that everything gets decrypted correctly.

Comment: Is it the right interpretation that not only can the public key overflow a+m, but that it is expected? Could you please elaborate on how delta affects protecting the message from overflow? I understand how it can be used to maintain precision, but I still don't see the how the plaintext message could be preserved after the encryption process, given that the addition of a results in a modular overflow .

Comment: Yes, it's mandatory. Maybe I was a bit imprecise, but you don't have to protect $m$ from the overflow, but rather from the errors. The overflow is just part of the system.
Say, you work modulo $Q$ and encode $m \in {0,...,T-1}$ with $\Delta m$, and $\Delta = Q/T$. Then you add error(s) $e$ due to computations. That means, you have a ciphertext like $(a,-a*s+\Delta m +e)$. Meanwhile, you work mod $Q$ and overflow.

Comment: As you decrypt the $-a*s$ part gets removed first. Then you perform a rounded integer division by $\Delta^{-1}$ and if $round(\Delta^{-1} e) = 0$, because $e$ is small enough, you retrieve $m$ correctly.